# Object id's in jstack

Tags: java, jvm, deadlock, jstack

I ran into a deadlock in my system, and here are excerpts from 2 jstacks taken a few minutes apart

Jstack 1

```
Found one Java-level deadlock:
=============================
"com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007f1ad075d2e8 (object 0x00007f1aed690ff8, a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet),
  which is held by "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1"
"com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007f1ad075d390 (object 0x00007f1aed4ca6c8, a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection),
  which is held by "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2"
```

Jstack 2

```
Found one Java-level deadlock:
=============================
"com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007f1ad075d2e8 (object 0x00007f1aec62c8a8, a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet),
  which is held by "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1"
"com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007f1ad075d390 (object 0x00007f1aec6077b8, a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection),
  which is held by "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2"
```

In both the jstacks, the monitor id's are the same
 *0x00007f1ad075d2e8* and *0x00007f1ad075d390*,
but the object id's are different.

There is clearly a deadlock, why are the object id's different?
Shouldn't they be same?